# Converting UTC time to dynamic timezones

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, utc

I want to convert the UTC **timestamp** given as **1623715897** and the **timezone** value as **19800** to the time in **'%H:%M:%S'**. I got this information from open weather API and I did not know how to convert to the given time including timezone value.

I used this code but got the time in UTC.

```
from datetime import datetime
ts = 1623715897
tz = 19800
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

I am not finding the solution for using tz (timezone) value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to utilize `timezone` and `timedelta` from `datetime`

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
ts = 1623715897
tz = 19800
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
'00:11:37'

>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, tz=timezone(timedelta(seconds=19800))).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
'05:41:37'
```

Comment: side note, utcfromtimestamp is kind of ok if you format to string like this, but better [avoid it](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html) if working with datetime objects.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was searching for the last 2 hours and didn't get any result.